# Flash or object tag inside an anchor link

Tags: html

Is it possible to insert a link to the object tag where after you click it you will be redirected to that link?

I already tried this:

```
<a href="LINK"><OBJECT TAG></a>
```

and even this:

```
<OBJECT TAG height="109"><a href="LINK" style="margin-top:-109px;"></a>
```

The first one is working on Chrome but in the other web browser I can't click the link.

So basically, is it really possible to link an object/flash object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming adding a button in the flash object is out of the question, in that case you can position the anchor over the flash object, using "position: absolute" and z-index (optional). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qbK5Q/ (I haven't used an actual flash object, but it should work with one):

```
<div class="objectContainer">
    <object>...</object>
    <a href="#">Test link</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255,112,0,0.5);
}
.objectContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
```

If it's a flash object, make sure that it has the "wmode" param set to "transparent" or "opaque". The problem with this solution is that the link will cover the flash object making it inaccessible to your mouse cursor (buttons and mouse events inside flash won't be accessible to the user).

Comment: Thank you very much! You solved my problem. The main key is this:
If it's a flash object, make sure that it has the "wmode" param set to "transparent" or "opaque".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post, but at least now you can make the link clickable also like this:

```
a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

object {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: `a` can also have `z-index: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but I have a better workaround.

```css
a {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

a > .fallback {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 1;
background: transparent;
}

a > object {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com" title="EXAMPLE.COM ANCHOR">
<object type="application/pdf" data="https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"></object> <!-- PDF iS FOR SHOWCASE -->
<span class="fallback">YOUR SITE TITLE</span>
</a>
```