# Javascript onclick in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, flash

I want to add flash banner with link to Wordpress:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="clickBanner(\''.$linkurl.'\')">
<object>
<param name="movie" value="'.$thead->image_url.'">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<embed wmode=transparent allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" src="'.$thead->image_url.'"></embed>
</object>
</a>
```

This code works good in Firefox, in Internet Explorer work only when double click, in Chrome it doesn't work , I click but link doesn't work.

If I use `onMouseDown()` it works but I don't need popup.

Comment: Where is your clickBanner function?

Comment: In `header.php` after `</head>`

Comment: No escape is needed. clickBanner(\''.$linkurl.'\') should be clickBanner('.$linkurl.')

Comment: @Derek bad idea not not work in all browsers

Comment: check answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356278/flash-or-object-tag-inside-an-anchor-link

Comment: @Derek This is apparently an excerpt from a PHP string that's delimited by `'`. That's why the escaped quotes are needed.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, forgot it is extracted PHP.