# Flash item in anchor tag is not working in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, flash, firefox, anchor

I am using some flash items in my anchor tag, but anchor tag was not click-able so I found this solution
[Flash or object tag inside an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356278/flash-or-object-tag-inside-an-anchor-link)
now I can click it in Chrome and IE but not in firefox. 
Please help me in this
My code :

```
<div style='position: relative;    width: 350px;'>
<object width='350' height='350'>
    <param wmode="transparent" name='movie' value='img=2-3_1_4.swf'>
    <embed src='img=2-3_1_4.swf' width='350' height='350' />
</object>
<a target='_blank' href='http://www.google.com' style='display: block;    position: absolute;    width: 100%;    height: 100%; 
          z-index: 5;    top: 0px;    left: 0px;' ></a>
```

Please get a DEMO [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pnema191/S6FPj/2)

Comment: can you post a DEMO please.

Comment: Please get a DEMO here http://jsfiddle.net/pnema191/S6FPj/2/